# td {position:relative; left} does not move the border

Tags: css, position

Please see the following example: 
 http://jsfiddle.net/6t6hq/7/

when I use td with position relative to move it,
it only move the content but not the border.
How can I move the border with the content?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="relativeTD">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="expected">expected</div>​
<style>
td{
    border:1px solid #000;
    min-width:100px;
}
#relativeTD{
    position:relative;
    left:60px;
}
#expected{
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    left:60px;
}​
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TD is of `display: table-cell;`!

So you can't move it using `relative position`ing. Instead, create another `<div>` inside the `<td>` and give `border` and stuff.

---

Instead, give `position: absolute` for the `td`. It works! Also, you need to give `position: relative` to the `table`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6t6hq/9/

---

Else, you can use `margin-left` too to the `td`.

Comment: If you are suggesting position absolute, be sure you have wrapped it inside `position: relative;` container...anyways that's a bad idea

Comment: @Mr.Alien JUst asking. Isn't table by default, position relative?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot move a single td border you need to move the whole table

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6t6hq/8/)

```
table {
   margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Either what you can do is give your table `border: 0;`, place a `div` inside your `td`
 give it some width, border and `position: relative` with `left: 60px;` and you are good to go